# value of $x(\sqrt 2)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

Suppose $x:[0,\infty) \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ is continuous and $x(0)=0$ and if

$$ x(t)^2 \leq 2+ \int _0 ^tx(s)ds $$

for all $t\geq 0$, then which of the following is true?

1) $x(\sqrt 2)\in [0, 2]$

2) $x(\sqrt 2)\in [0, \frac{3}{\sqrt 2}]$

3) $x(\sqrt 2)\in [\frac{5}{\sqrt 2}, \frac{7}{\sqrt 2}]$

4) $x(\sqrt 2)\in [10,\infty]$

I do using equality of the above relation and answer I got $1/ \sqrt 2$

Comment: please help someone.

Comment: Are you sure those are the options? I also got $x\left(\sqrt2\right)\in\left[0, \frac1{\sqrt2}\right]$

Comment: is there only one right answer?

Comment: yes option are correct and one answer is correct

Comment: if there is only one answer you don't need to calculate anything to know it is  (2). (3) and (4) can't be true because x(t)=0 is a valid function, and if it is (1) it is also (2) because $[0,2]\in\left[0, \frac3{\sqrt2}\right]$

Answer (score 1):

Let $$y(t):=2+\int_0^t{x(s)}ds\geq 2$$
Then from the intgral inequality we have
$$\dot{y}=x(t)\leq \sqrt{y}$$
or equivalently
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(2{y^{1/2}(t)}-t\right)\leq 0$$
which yields
$$2y^{1/2}(t)-t\leq 2y^{1/2}(0)=2\sqrt{2}$$
i.e.
$$y^{1/2}(t)\leq \frac{t}{2}+\sqrt{2}$$
From the initial inequality we have
$$x(t)\leq \left(2+\int_0^t{x(s)ds}\right)^{1/2}=y^{1/2}(t)\leq \frac{t}{2}+\sqrt{2} $$
For $t=\sqrt{2}$ we obtain from above
$$x(\sqrt{2})\leq \frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}$$